# The problem with the eyes and jaw in the Blender

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

Hello everyone I can’t solve the problem in any way. When controlling the eyes and mouth, everything works well, but when you turn your head, the jaw rotates faster (with a larger radius than the head), and the eyes remain motionless. Maybe someone has encountered this? Please tell me how to fix it… Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, I don't see the problem for the jaw, are you talking about the teeth? As for the eyes, you need to parent them to the good bones

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about teeth. There is no problem with the tongue. Teeth, when turning the shoulders, come out of the head. And the eyes behind the movement of the head do not move at all.

Comment: For the teeth, they are already parented to a bone, so you don't need their Armature modifier, remove them. For the eyes, they are parented to MCH-eye.L and MCH-eye.R but these bones don't move when you move the head, you need to parent them to a parent bone, you need to understand how the bone hierarchy works for the head

Comment: Also same thing for the eyes, remove their Armature modifiers, they don't need both the Armature modifier + classic bone parenting

Comment: Thank you:) I got confused about it, although at first everything was fine :) I'll try to build it all over again.

Answer (score 0):

For the teeth, they are already parented to a bone, so you don't need their *Armature* modifier, remove them, otherwise the influences will cumulate. Same thing for the eyes. Also they are parented to *MCH-eye.L* and *MCH-eye.R* but these bones don't move when you move the head, you need to parent them to the correct parent bone, you need to understand how the bone hierarchy works for the head to find this bone.

Comment: I did everything as you wrote. Everything works fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Goryachkin Camera Great then   ;)